# CSS variables in SAPUI5 applications using sap web ide

Tags: css, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I want to set up some basic color codes in my css file.

My css looks as below:

```
 @colorGood: #32CD32;
    @colorOk: #FFA500;
    @colorBad: #FF4500;

    .testClass{
         width: 80%;
         background: @colorGood;
    }
```

My XML has a button control as below:

```
<Button id="testBtn" class="testClass" />
```

I create the above view and css in the web-ide. When I run it, it does not show take the color mentioned in the variable.

1. Is it possible to have variables in CSS [since the SAPUI5 library already contains less pre-processor].
2. Is this the correct way to implement this in webide?
3. Also any example to acheive this through the eclipse/HANA Studio IDE would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Once I had to use my own CSS file and one thing was obligatory: to include the custom CSS. Not sure if it is the best practice thing; at least worked for me: in my Component init code I added the following:

```
jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet({
    url: jQuery.sap.getResourcePath("<full path to the CSS file>"),
    id: "custom_style"
});
```

where  includes also your name space. Say your name space is **com.foo.project** and the css file with name **mystyle.css** is stored in **css** project folder, then you full path would be:
"com/foo/project/css/mystyle.css".

Comment: I already have my custom css file. I am referring to it in the index.html through the <link> tag which works fine. I wanted to use variables to store color hex codes and use it instead of hardcoding the hex code in css as we do in scss files 

e.g.@good : "#39a651" and then use it in any class as

.customTextColor{
     color: @good;
}